# MATLAB R2014a create tabs on tabs (uitabgroup)

Tags: matlab, tabs

I created a tabbed pane with  some tabs using **uitabgroup** and added another uitabgroup on one of the tabs. Code is something like this:

```
fh = figure;
tabs1 = uitabgroup('Parent', fh);
tab1 = uitab(tabs1, 'title', 'Tab1');
tab2 = uitab(tabs1, 'title', 'Tab2');

th1 = uicontrol('Parent', tab1, 'Style', 'text', 'String', 'Should be on tab1');

tabs2 = uitabgroup('Parent', tab1);
tab3 = uitab(tabs2, 'title', 'Tab3');
tab4 = uitab(tabs2, 'title', 'Tab4');

th2 = uicontrol('Parent', tab4, 'Style', 'text', 'String', 'Should be on tab4 which is on tab1');

th3 = uicontrol('Parent', tab2, 'Style', 'text', 'String', 'Should be on tab2');
```

But after adding the second uitabgroup, the content of tab2 doesn't show.
Only if I add 2 more tabs after tab2, the content shows on the last one.

Something like this:

```
tabs1 = uitabgroup('Parent', fh);
tab1 = uitab(tabs1, 'title', 'Tab1');
tab2 = uitab(tabs1, 'title', 'Tab2');
tab5 = uitab(tabs1, 'title', 'Tab5');
tab6 = uitab(tabs1, 'title', 'Tab6');

th1 = uicontrol('Parent', tab1, 'Style', 'text', 'String', 'Should be on tab1');

tabs2 = uitabgroup('Parent', tab1);
tab3 = uitab(tabs2, 'title', 'Tab3');
tab4 = uitab(tabs2, 'title', 'Tab4');
th2 = uicontrol('Parent', tab4, 'Style', 'text', 'String', 'Should be on tab4 which is on tab1');

th3 = uicontrol('Parent', tab2, 'Style', 'text', 'String', 'Should be on tab2');
```

th3 shows on tab6!! even the parent is tab2 and there are 2 empty tabs between them. 
I know that it is not possible to make tabs invisible (even with Java).
Is there a way to make this work properly?
I really need tabs on tabs.

Edit: 
Made mistake with tab numbers.

Here is a pic showing what is happening:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhisqfrjxose8u9/tabs.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rhisqfrjxose8u9/tabs.png?dl=0

Comment: Your second group is a child of Tab1... Also, why do you need two rows of tabs? Space constrained?

Comment: Your example code does not reproduce the issue described on my machine.

Comment: Second group should be on tab1 but the content of other 'main' tabs doesn't show properly after adding 'mini' tabs.
If there were 6 'mini' tabs, to show content of the tab2, there should be also 6 more 'main' tabs.

I need this because there are lots of gui objects and I have practically finished the whole app, just needed to combine tabs. 
Creating menus is not an option.

Comment: Again, your example code functions as expected on my machine.

Comment: @exacaza Did you add or remove something? Because on my machine does not show properly.  I posted a pic.

Comment: Why would I add or remove something and then say your code doesn't reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer. This is a bug in MATLAB.

[Original post with answer is here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/tab-panels-uitab-and-relatives#comment-276302)

"In $matlab/toolbox/matlab/uitools/@uitools/**@uitabgroup**/**schema.m**, the function **updateVisibilityOfTabs** (line 250 in R2014a):

```
children = handle(findobj(getVisibleChildren(tabgroupRef),'Type','uitab');
```

Need to add

```
,'Parent',tabgroupRef);
```

to that call.

In $matlab/toolbox/matlab/uitools/@uitools/**@uitab**/**updateVisibility.m**:

```
children = handle(findobj(get(tabgroup,'Chilren'),'Type','uitab');
```

Add a similar Parent identifier:

```
,'Parent',tabgroup);
```